# How do i save an object required for a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I an actionbar with 2 tabs (2 ListFragment) and both require an object to load it's UI. This object will be retrieved using retrofit but my problem is that every time i switch tabs the content will be loaded again from the web, so i need a way to preserve this object between fragment states.

I'm thinking about saving it in the main activity so each fragment would have a "storage place" for it's own object.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: if the object doesn't change once you retrive it use Sharedpreference to save it

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: Thanks i will check both options. If the cost to obtain that object is too high and the app may need 10 different objects for different scenarios, it's okay to consider to save and restore from cache? (using files), i'm not sure about what's the amount of memory per object, it does not include bitmaps or anything else... but i fear that the app would spend too much memory if i just save/restore using main activity as Afsa suggested.